# Return overload fails

Tags: powershell, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm following this little write up: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher but I'm doing it from Powershell.  so what I have so far is

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\...\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net40\NewtonSoft.Json.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\...\Neo4jClient.1.0.0.662\lib\net40\Neo4jClient.dll")

$neo = new-object Neo4jClient.GraphClient(new-object Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"))
$q=$neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return({param($m) $m});
```

with which I would mean to retrieve all nodes in the database.  the `Return()` method is shown in the example to require a lambda expression as a parameter, which in Powershell would be a code-block, however, I get the following error:

> Cannot find an overload for "Return" and the argument count: "1". At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + $q=$neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return({param($m) $m});
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

where am I going wrong?

*** Update I ***

with the explanation provided by @PetSerAl below, I've managed to get a little further, but I'm still stuck.  below I will quote the write up (c#) and then show the equivalent powershell.  first we declare a class

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

my class differs a little

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "public class Project { public string Code; public string Name; public string Parent; public string Lifespan; }"
```

their Cypher

```
MATCH (user:User)
RETURN user
```

their c#

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .Return(user => user.As<User>())
    .Results
```

now my cypher

```
MATCH (n:Project)
RETURN n
```

...and finally, my attempt at the powershell:

```
$exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]
$p = $exp::Constant("Project")
$fn = $exp::TypeAs($p, (new-object Project).GetType())
$return = $exp::Lambda([Func[Project]], $fn, $p)
$neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return($return)
```

but I get an error

> Exception calling "Return" with "1" argument(s): "The expression must
>   be constructed as either an object initializer (for  example: n => new
>   MyResultType { Foo = n.Bar }), an anonymous type initializer (for
>   example: n => new { Foo = n.Bar }), a  method call (for example: n =>
>   n.Count()), or a member accessor (for example: n => n.As().Bar).
>   You cannot supply  blocks of code (for example: n => { var a = n + 1;
>   return a; }) or use constructors with arguments (for example: n => new
>   Foo(n)). If you're in F#, tuples are also supported. Parameter name:
>   expression" At line:1 char:1
>   + $neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return($return)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

which, for once, is actually very clear and understandable.  so what I want is a method call e.g. `n => n.Count()` and clearly did not achieve that.

help?

*** Update II ***

so, continuing on with the torturous path of neo4j from powershell, I've given @PetSerAl's second approach a stab and got a little further.  here's what I managed to write:

```
$neopath = "C:\[...]\Neo4jClient.dll"
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $neopath -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using Neo4jClient.Cypher;
    public class Project {
        public string Code;
        public string Name;
        public string Parent;
        public string Lifespan;
    };
    public static class NeoExp {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherResultItem,Project>> GetProject = (n) => n.As<Project>();
}
"@
```

which now allows me to do:

```
$neo.Cypher.Match("n:Project").Return([NeoExp]::GetProject)
```

and that, miraculously, works! except it brings me back no data:

```
Results ResultsAsync Query                         Client 
------- ------------ -----                         ------                                                                      
                     Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQ... Neo4jClient.GraphClient
```

and I know I have projects in the database... so what could the issue be now?

*** Update III ***

wow, so close but still not done. as per the latest suggestion from @PetSerAl.  I tried:

```
$neo.Cypher.Match("n:Project").Return([NeoExp]::GetProject).get_Results()
```

which yielded an illuminating error:

> Exception calling "get_Results" with "0" argument(s): "The graph
>   client is not connected to the server. Call the Connect method first."

so that made it clear I first needed to do:

```
$neo.Connect()
```

also, I needed parentheses around the query's match clause:

```
$neo.Cypher.Match("(n:Project)").Return([NeoExp]::GetProject)
```

now I get 27 results back as expected in the `.Results` field... however, the results are all blank.  so I think maybe it has to do with the `n.As<Project>()` where perhaps my class isn't defined properly and that fails.  any thoughts?

*** Update IV ***

ok, got it.  the `Project` class needs to have properties, not fields:

```
    public class Project {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Parent { get; set; }
        public string Lifespan { get; set; }
    };
```

and that's it.  I have data.  yea!!!

@PetSelAl: I owe you a beer

Comment: Show results of `$neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return.OverloadDefinitions`.

Comment: @PetSerAl, the output was too large to paste here so I put it here: http://pastebin.com/sLQELWMu

Comment: incidentally, I see in the list there's an overload for this method that accepts a single string, so I tried this: `.Return("n")` but it results in the same error

Comment: Write it this way: `$neo.Cypher.Match("n:Project").Return([NeoExp]::GetProject).get_Results()`. Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a million thanks to @PetSerAl who explained the problem well in its essence, and who held my hand through its resolution.

to restate, the problem is that Powershell has no built-in mechanism to call generic methods and the Neo4jClient library's `.Return` method overloads are all generic.  Specifically, Powershell provides no means of supplying the type of the method.

so there are several ways to solve this:

- one solution is to use reflection to make the call, but the task is a bit tricky.  thankfully the approach has been tackled by a project available on tech net.  see: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-Generic-Methods-bf7675af
- the second solution suggested in @PetSerAl's reply needed a little help but with @ChrisSkardon's help I got it to work.  see here: [Constructing a method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514603/constructing-a-method-call)
- and the third solution (see the Updates in the original post) which relies on creating a c# class with a method where the generic method can be called

I expect to be documenting this solution in the wiki for Neo4jClient and I hope the effort documented here is helpful to others.  Thanks again @PetSerAl for all your help

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: better? the link may become invalid but if it does the solution is no longer available and that can't be helped, the answer is still good, yes?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with `Return` method:

1. It accepts argument of expression tree type, rather then compiled delegate type. And PowerShell does not have an easy way to create expression tree from a `ScriptBlock`. So, you have to create expression tree by hands or use `string` overload.
2. `string` overload does not allows PowerShell to infer generic parameter for method, and PowerShell syntax does not allows to specifying generic parameter explicitly. So, PowerShell can not call `string` overload of `Return` method directly. You have to use some workaround to call it, for example, call it thru `Reflection`.

Sample how can you create a simple expression tree (`(a,b) => a*2+b`) in PowerShell:

```powershell
# First way: messing with [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]
$a=[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter([int],'a')
$b=[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter([int],'b')
$2=[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Constant(2)

$Body=[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Add([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Multiply($a,$2),$b)
$Sum=[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda([Func[int,int,int]],$Body,$a,$b)
$Sum

# Second way: using help of C#
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    public static class MyExpression {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<int,int,int>> Sum=(a,b) => a*2+b;
    }
'@
[MyExpression]::Sum
```

Comment: could you explain a little? "`string` overload does not allow Ps to infer generic parameter for method" - the method declares a string as a parameter, so if I were to call it: `.Return([string] $s)` that would indicate I'm passing a string to the method... but I still get the error "Cannot find an overload for 'Return' and the argument count: 1" - how come?

Comment: @ekkis `Return` have type parameter `TResult` and PowerShell can not infer it. `.Return([string] $s)`: is it `.Return<int>([string] $s)`, `.Return<char>([string] $s)`, `.Return<string>([string] $s)`, or `.Return<SomethingElse>([string] $s)`? And PowerShell does not have a syntax to specify `<TypeName>` explicitly.

Comment: oh... I understand.  then I'm screwed... what I need is a non-generic version of that method.  this is a big omission in Powershell.  so address your first point, how then would I create an expression tree in Psh?

Comment: @ekkis Add couple expression tree examples.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you're asking, and might not even be what you want, but you could [create your own C# class right inside PowerShell using `Add-Type`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914(v=wps.620).aspx). It might be easier to implement it that way and provide simple methods you can use within the PowerShell code if what you're writing relies on a lot of C#-specific things.

This example is taken straight from the link above:

```powershell
$source = @"
public class BasicTest
{
  public static int Add(int a, int b)
  {
    return (a + b);
  }
  public int Multiply(int a, int b)
  {
    return (a * b);
  }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source
[BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)
$basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
$basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply but it really doesn't address my issue at all

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell is that you're using it wrong. Your object structure should be your `Neo4jClient` object, which should then have a few properties and methods. I am pretty sure that `Return` is a property, not a method. So I'm thinking something more like:

```
$neo = new-object Neo4jClient.GraphClient(new-object Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"))
$neo.Cypher.Match = "n"
$neo.Cypher.Return = {param($m) $m}
$q = $neo.Cypher.Results()
```

There you create your object, you define the `Match` filter, define what you want it to return (everything from the looks of it), and then store the results in the `$q` variable. I'm pretty sure that should be the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data")) WHERE "n"
```

I also kind of wonder about your `Match` criteria, since they seem to be specifying property/value pairs in their examples and you just give one of the two. If that fails I would strongly suggest doing a `$neo.Cypher | Get-Member` to see what properties you have, what they're typed as, and what methods you have.

**Edit:** Ok, so I did look at the link. I also downloaded the libraries, loaded them into PowerShell, and looked at the .Net objects. Return is indeed a method, and the overloads for it are ridiculous. There are 37 overloads for it, the longest of which is almost 750 characters. Most of them are `ICypherResultItem` expressions, but the simplest is `(string identity)`. Might I suggest simply trying `Return("*")`?

Comment: `Return` is a method.  see the "Starting a query" section in the link I provided.  it gets passed a lambda expression