# How to read method signature?

Tags: .net, powershell, neo4j, neo4jclient

if I review the overloads available for the `Return` method, which I can do like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\...\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net40\NewtonSoft.Json.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\...\Neo4jClient.1.0.0.662\lib\net40\Neo4jClient.dll")

$neo = new-object Neo4jClient.GraphClient(new-object Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"))
$q=$neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return({param($m) $m});
$neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return.OverloadDefinitions
```

I see something like this:

> Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery[TResult] Return[TResult](string identity)
>
> Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery[TResult] Return[TResult](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[System.Func[TResult]] expression)
>
> Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery[TResult] Return[TResult](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[System.Func[Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherResultItem,TResult]] expression)

from which I read that the first overload takes a single string parameter, however, how do I read the second overload? it takes a linq expression, which [contains|accepts] a parameterless function that returns type `TResult`?

and what about the third, where the function takes 2 parameters? is it two parameters or one parameter and a return type?

how do I read this syntax?

Comment: The `OverloadDefinitions` are simply method signatures. Look up the documentation for the Neo4jClient assembly if you need further information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so one part of the answer is that the output replaces the normal angle brackets with square brackets, so this:

```
Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery[TResult] Return[TResult](string identity)
```

should actually be this:

```
Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery<TResult> Return<TResult>(string identity)
```

so it's now clear that these are generics (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

which means to say that:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TResult>>
```

means a linq expression typed as a function that returns `TResult`

Answer (score 2):

[This source file](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/blob/master/Neo4jClient/Cypher/ICypherFluentQuery.cs) should provide the signatures in a readable manner.

Comment: ah... so the angle brackets of the normal notation get replaced with square brackets, to indicate generics... ok

Comment: in fact, this question was prompted by another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314696/return-overload-fails that perhaps you could answer?