# Constructing a method call

Tags: powershell, neo4jclient

in trying to follow this guide: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#get-all-users-by-label
I need to create a lambda expression in order to provide it to the `Return` method.  In C# it looks like this:

```
.Return(n => n.As<Project>())
```

and in Powershell I've gone about it this way (as per @PetSerAl's suggestion: [Return overload fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314696/return-overload-fails)):

```
$exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]
$param = $exp::Parameter([Neo4jClient.Cyper.ICypherResultItem], "n")
$body = $exp::TypeAs($p, (new-object Project).GetType())
$lambda = $exp::Lambda([Func[Project]], $body, $p)
```

such that the parameter passed to the lambda expression is typed to receive what the Neo4j expression will pass and the body of the method converts it to a `Project` (a locally defined class).  now I can pass it to my method:

```
$something.Return($lambda)
```

however, I get this error

> Exception calling "Return" with "1" argument(s): "The expression must
>   be constructed as either an object initializer (for example: n => new
>   MyResultType { Foo = n.Bar }), an anonymous type initializer (for
>   example: n => new { Foo = n.Bar }), a method call (for example: n =>
>   n.Count()), or a member accessor (for example: n => n.As().Bar). You
>   cannot supply blocks of code (for example: n => { var a = n + 1;
>   return a; }) or use constructors with arguments (for example: n => new
>   Foo(n)). If you're in F#, tuples are also supported. Parameter name:
>   expression" At line:1 char:1 + $neo.Cypher.Match("n").Return($return)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

which makes it clear I didn't formulate the body of the lambda expression correctly.  can anyone suggest how it should be instead?

Comment: Have you tried the second way suggested (with the help of `c#`)? Even if it's just to test that it can work before reverting to creating `Expressions` the way you're trying to. I think you'll want something like: `Expression<Func<ICypherResultItem, Project>> Proj=(n) => n.As<Project>();`

Comment: yes, the second way PetSerAl suggested works, but this would be a bit cleaner and I just want to figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `C#` you have:

```
.Return(n => n.As<Project>())
```

If we take that out and look at the type, `n => n.As<Project>()` is:

```
Expression<Func<ICypherResultItem, Project>>
```

To create that using `Expression Trees` in `C#`, we end up doing something like:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (ICypherResultItem), "n");
MethodCallExpression right = Expression.Call(parameter, typeof (ICypherResultItem).GetMethod("As").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Project)));
Expression<Func<ICypherResultItem, Project>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ICypherResultItem, Project>>(right, parameter);
```

So, converting that to PowerShell *I think* it's something like:

```
$exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]
$param = $exp::Parameter([Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherResultItem], "n")
$body = $exp::Call($param, [Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherResultItem].GetMethod("As").MakeGenericMethod[Project])
$lambda = $exp::Lambda([Func[ICypherResultItem, Project]], $body, $param)
```

I am in **no way** a powershell person, and I suspect you'll be able to translate the `C#` better, but hopefully this will get you onto the right track...

*** Update I ***
a small fix that makes it all work.  declare a var to hold the array of types that `MakeGenericMethod` expects, and pass that in:

```
$PrjType = @((new-object Project).GetType())
$body = $exp::Call($param, [Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherResultItem].GetMethod("As").MakeGenericMethod($PrjType))
```

Comment: hallelujah.  that was pretty close.  I've made a small fix and I now get data back.  yea!!!