# Call C# Method with Expression<Func> Parameter From Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, lambda

I have the following sample C# class:

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static string Method1(Expression<Func<string>> efs)
    {
        return efs.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```

To call this from C# it's as easy as:

```
Class1.Method1(() => "Hello World");
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to call this from Powershell.  My last attempt is:

```
Add-Type -Path "ClassLibrary1.dll"
$func = [Func[string]] { return "Hello World" }
$exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Call($func.Method);
[ClassLibrary1.Class1]::Method1($exp)
```

But this results in an error:

```
Exception calling "Call" with "1" argument(s): "Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.String lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure)'"
At C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\test.ps1:4 char:1
+ $exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Call($func.Method);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
+ $exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Call($func.Method);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I believe my `$func` is incorrect; any ideas?

Comment: I don't see an overload of `Expression.Call` that takes a single argument. That is what the error is telling you as well.

Comment: @DavidG, no, that results in `Cannot convert argument "efs", with value: "System.Func`1[System.String]", for "Method1" to type "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`1[System.String]]"`, which is why I was trying to create an `Expression` from the `Func`.

Comment: @JasonBoyd, good point, when I type the analogous in C# `Func<string> func = () => "Hello World"; Expression.Call(func.Method);`, it's using the signature: `public static MethodCallExpression Call(MethodInfo method, params Expression[] arguments)`, now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to call that...

Comment: That's interesting. When I try that in LinqPad I get `Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.Parameter name: method`

Comment: You're also trying to convert a Func to an Expression which isn't really possible. Does it need to be an Expression? Because that would work very simply.

Comment: @JasonBoyd, yes, just hit that.  I took a step back and am trying to figure how how to do it in `C#` by creating the expression directly.  Stuck on that one too.

Comment: @DavidG, yes, can't change the signature of the method I'm calling.  I think my attempted implementation is a red herring, here.

Comment: Not sure it's possible to create an expression from PowerShell though

Comment: This will create an expression in c#: `Expression<Func<string>> exp = () => "Hello World";`

Comment: To create an expression you'd have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30598459/1663001). Otherwise it's probably far easier to make your own class library that wraps it up for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, figured it out (thanks to @DavidG for the link).  The key was to write out the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` tree in C# first.  Then, converting to Powershell was easy after that:

So, in C# this:

```
Class1.Method1(() => "Hello World");
```

is analogous to:

```
var exp = Expression.Constant("Hello World", typeof(string));
var lamb = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp);
Class1.Method1(lamb);
```

In Powershell:

```
$exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Constant("Hello World", [string]);
$lamb = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda([Func[string]], $exp);
[ClassLibrary1.Class1]::Method1($lamb);
```